# Swift XCTest access Private variables

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, private, xctest

I have code similar to the below snippet

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

      private var bLogin = true
}
```

From XCTest file, how can I access "bLogin" variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swift 2.0 add `@testable` to the import statement:

```
@testable import MyMainModule
```

Comment: I am using Swift 1.2 :(

Comment: In that case you have to add the source file to the test project and change access modifier from `private` to `internal`. There isn't a good way to test private methods in Swift 1.2